# Most Concise Way to Transpose SQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I transpose this table so I have two columns, one column showing the ratio for paid users and one column showing the ratio for free users. Also, in my script are there any ways I can make the code more concise and 'SQL' like? It also seems that I cannot create a table using a select statement in sqlfiddle as I get an error saying it can only be created in the schema screen. Is there anyway I can embed the sql statement into a new table?

I have created a script on sqlfiddle that calculates some download metrics for different types of users: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79bea4/1

Comment: Why was this question downvoted, other than for being messy?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT df.Date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ad.paying_customer = 'No'
                THEN df.downloads ELSE 0 END) /
       SUM(CASE WHEN ad.paying_customer = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Average Downloads/Free User`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ad.paying_customer = 'Yes'
                THEN df.downloads ELSE 0 END) /
       SUM(CASE WHEN ad.paying_customer = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Average Downloads/Paid User`
FROM
(
    SELECT date,
           user_id,
           SUM(downloads) AS downloads
    FROM download_facts
    GROUP BY date,
             user_id
) df
INNER JOIN user_dimension ud
    ON df.user_id = ud.user_id
INNER JOIN account_dimension ad
    ON ud.account_id = ad.account_id
GROUP BY df.Date
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the average by taking the sum of the downloads and dividing by the number of users.  Then `count(distinct)` can get the users in each group:

```
select df.date,
       (sum(df.downloads) /
        count(distinct case when ad.paying_customer = 'No' then df.user_id end)
       ) as avg_free,   
       (sum(df.downloads) /
        count(distinct case when ad.paying_customer = 'Yes' then df.user_id end)
       ) as avg_paying   
from download_facts df left join
     user_dimension ud
     on df.user_id = ud.user_id left join
     account_dimension ad
     on ad.account_id = ud.account_id
group by df.date;
```